# Accepting an undefined number of arguments in Ruby/Inline C

Tags: c, ruby, variadic-functions, splat, ruby-c-extension

I am trying to rewrite a highly recursive function using inline C with Ruby. The function accepts an undefined number of arguments, i.e. it would look like this in Ruby:

```
    def each_entity(*types)
      # Do something and recurse.
    end
```

I am trying to mimick this in inline C using the following code:

```
    VALUE each_entity_c(int argc, VALUE *argv)
    {
      // ...
    }
```

But this yields the compile error:

```
inline.rb:486:in `ruby2c': Unknown type "VALUE *" (ArgumentError)
```

Is this the correct way to accomplish this in C? If so, what could have caused this error? If not, how is it done?

Comment: Where did you declared `VALUE`?

Comment: Does C's `...` not do what you want?

Comment: @asaeler, VALUE is defined in the Ruby C core - "in C the type of all Ruby variables is VALUE, which is either a pointer to a Ruby object or an immediate value" (from the [Pickaxe](http://rubycentral.com/pickaxe/ext_ruby.html)). I am pretty sure that VALUE is appropriately defined here, since I can define a function `VALUE each_entity_c(int test) { ... }` without any warnings raised.

Comment: @prelic, defining a function like this : `VALUE each_entity_c(VALUE arg1, ...)` yields "WARNING: '...' not understood."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [`builder.c`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/RubyInline/Inline/C.html#method-i-c), try [`builder.c_raw`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/RubyInline/Inline/C.html#method-i-c_raw) (or [`builder.c_raw_singleton`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/RubyInline/Inline/C.html#method-i-c_raw_singleton)) when defining your methods. You might want to add `VALUE self` to the end of the args list, but it seems to work with or without in my tests. It might also be worth explicitly specifying the arity, just to be safe:

```
inline do |builder|

  builder.c_raw <<-EOS, :arity => -1
    VALUE each_entity_c(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self)
    {
      // ...
    }
  EOS
end
```

Using `builder.c`, Ruby Inline will rewrite the function so that it accepts Ruby `VALUE` types as parameters, and add code to convert these to the c types in your original. You're writing code that already expects `VALUE` arguments so don't want this conversion to be done, so you need to use `c_raw`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to you this:

```
VALUE each_entity_c(VALUE self, VALUE args)
{
    // args is a Ruby array with all arguments
}
rb_define_method(class, "MyClass", each_entity_c, -2);
```

The C function is given a Ruby array with all arguments.